# how to get id of a table row with a class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the id value of a highlighted table row. My table html is like below

```
<table id="templateSite" class="table table-responsive show">    
<tr>
    <th>.....</th>
    <th>Name</th>        
</tr>   
 <tr id="32" class="highlight">
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I m trying the following selector but it does not work

```
$('#templateSite tr.highlight').attr('id').val()
```

Also just wondering if there is any good tool for Jquery selectors. I have tried few chrome extensions but nothing helps for a problem like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `.attr()` getter returns you the attribute value so there is no need to call `.val()`.

In this case `.attr('id')` returns a string value which does not have a method called `.val()` so you should get an error like `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
$('#templateSite tr.highlight').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun. It does work but any suggestions on a selector tool for these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.val()` from your syntax. You have to write only `.attr('id')` which will work for you.

```
$('#templateSite tr.highlight').attr('id');
```